# Deleting region in wavesurfer

Tags: wavesurfer.js

I came across the following example where you can delete a region = https://codepen.io/BusyBee/pen/NpvJBE

```
deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        region.remove();
    });
```

However you have to slightly move the region first in order to see the delete button.
Any ideas on how to make the delete button appear from the outset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is the problem :

```
wavesurfer.on('region-update-end', function(region, event){...}
```

You're tying to create the delete button on `region-update-end` event. this event only works When dragging or resizing is finished.
So if you want to do something when a region is created, simply replace `region-update-end` with `region-created` event.

```
wavesurfer.on('region-created', function(region, event){...}
```

Here is the link to the official documentation: https://wavesurfer-js.org/example/annotation/index.html